# I need to adjust the border of this ios icon

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, web, icons

My app icon is showing with white borders, how do I remove it?
this is happening only when I try to build the application for ios, on the android system this does not happen

I tried modifying the alpha channel but it didn't work.

image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvMpj.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your image has some white (or transparant) color on the edges.  If that's the case I would open the image in a image program, zoom in, find these spots and fill them with the background color.